# How to Use SystemJS for my angular9 project

Tags: systemjs, angular9

```
How to Use SystemJS for my angular9  project which has many components and spec files.
```

How to Use SystemJS for my angular9  project which has many components and spec files.

Answer (score 0):

Once you created an Angular project you would have many components and files.
Now open node terminal (open terminal from your ide) and write

`npm i systemjs`

and press enter.

(You can also see a folder will be created in node_modules for your systemjs)

Now you can import things from systemjs

i.e. `import XYZ from 'systemjs/XYZ';`